# Sum digits of previous numbers algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have sequence of numbers:
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 12, 7, 10...
Each number then is the sum of the separete digits of the previous elements.
It's a bit like Fibonacci..
I want to write a function

```
int FindSimilarFibo(int x)
{
//x = 10 return 10
//x = 6  return 8
}
```

I wrote this, but I can't figure out the correct algorithm:

```
int FindSimilarFibo(int x) {
    int p = 0;
    int q = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int temp = p;
    p = q;
    q = temp + q;
    if (q > 9) 
    {
        int leftQ = q % 10;
        int rightQ = q / 10;
        q = leftQ + rightQ;
        q = temp + q;

    }
    if (p > 9)
    {
        int leftQ = q % 10;
        int rightQ = q / 10;
        temp = leftQ + rightQ;
        p = q;
        q = temp + q;
    }

}
    return p;
}
```

Comment: How is this a searching algorithm? What exactly are you searching for?

Comment: @YashGupta I enter the index in the specified sequence into the function and it returns that number.

Comment: @Cesc to be fair, that doesn't make it a searching algorithm; there's no ... search

Comment: I've edited the title to better match the topic, indeed, nothing to do with search, besides... being an algorithm

Comment: Ok, I apologize for the misleading label.

Comment: Note: this sequence reaches a loop very quickly - from n=3 onwards, there is a loop of length 24, i.e. it restarts at n=27, n=51, n=75 etc; so if you wanted to, you could implement this with a pre-computed small array and a module check - or the version suggested by BurnsBA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem looks to be that you're overwriting previous values when computing the digits-sum of the next; so... don't do that? perhaps:

```cs
static int FindSimilarFibo(int n)
{
    int p = 0;
    int q = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var next = SumDigits(p) + SumDigits(q);
        p = q;
        q = next;
    }
    return p;

    static int SumDigits(int value)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (value > 9)
        {
            sum += value % 10;
            value /= 10;
        }
        return sum + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to avoid operators like +=, and especially /= as they feel very unnatural for beginners :) It's also worth noting that this solution works also for numbers larger than 99

Comment: @mikus IMO the intent is perfectly clear - this isn't exactly super-exotic niche syntax like some kind of ref-return indexer - this is core commonly-used syntax, so... I don't think we should be shy of showing it to anyone

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, I think that's clean and clear too.

Comment: well, I'd say... let's adapt style to the level of question :D

Answer (score 2):

If you search for your sequence at the The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences you will find this at [A010077](https://oeis.org/A010077).

One implementation is given as

```
a(n) = floor(a(n-1)/10) + floor(a(n-2)/10) + (a(n-1) mod 10) + (a(n-2) mod 10)
```

Or in c#

```cs
public int A010077(int n)
{
    int n_2 = 0;
    int n_1 = 1;
    int value = 0;
    
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        value = (n_1 / 10) + (n_2 / 10) + (n_1 % 10) + (n_2 % 10);
        n_2 = n_1;
        n_1 = value;
    }
    
    return value;
}
```

For example

```cs
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(A010077)
```

gives

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 12, 7, 10, 8, 9, 17, 17, 16, 15, 13, 10, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print out all the values of this sequence, you'll see this:

0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 12, 7, 10, 8, 9, 17, 17, 16, 15, 13, 10, 5, 6, 11, 8, 10, 9, 10, 10, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 12, 7, 10, 8, 9, 17, 17, 16, 15, 13, 10, 5, 6, 11, 8, 10, 9, 10, 10

Inspection reveals that the sequence repeats starting with `2, 3, 5, 8` and ending with `10, 9, 10, 10`.

Given this, we can write a non-looping solution like this:

```
public static int FindSimilarFibo(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    if (x <= 2)
        return 1;

    int[] values = { 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 12, 7, 10, 8, 9, 17, 17, 16, 15, 13, 10, 5, 6, 11, 8, 10, 9, 10, 10 };

    return values[(x + values.Length - 3) % values.Length];
}
```